# how to use colfilt\ bloc_proc my own function

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to use `colfilt` but instead using one line function I want to apply some condition, for example:

```
I2 = colfilt(I,[50 50],'sliding',own_func);

function own_func(block_struct)
mean(block_struct.data);
if(block_struct.data<6000)
    block_struct.data=0;
else block_struct.data=255;
end
end
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo()
I = imread('tire.tif');
function y = complicated_function(x)
    %column to number
    y=mean(x);
end
I2 = uint8(colfilt(I,[5 5],'sliding',@complicated_function));
end
```

Comment: Please add some text to explain your answer.

Comment: @EBH this is how I passive aggressively communicate that the question isn't very good.